# how to extract Hour only from date time data that has UTC + 7 in Looker studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a table like this

| timestamp | datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 1679305394563192 | 2023-03-20 09:43:14.563192 UTC |
| 1679302803808587 | 2023-03-20 09:00:03.808587 UTC |

as you can see, the `datetime` is in UTC. I want to create a new calculated field in Looker Studio that convert it to be UTC + 7 but only the Hour

- If I have `2023-03-20 09:00:00 UTC` then it should return 16 in my UTC + 7 timezone
- If I have
  `2023-03-20 22:00:00 UTC` then it should return 5 (next day) in my UTC + 7 timezone

if I run this code

```
FORMAT_DATETIME("%H", datetime)
```

it will still return in UTC. if I add `+ 7` it will throw error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
DATETIME_ADD(
PARSE_DATETIME("%F %T",LEFT_TEXT(timestamp,19)),
INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
```

[image]

Comment: this code should be combined with `FORMAT_DATETIME("%H", datetime)` to get Hour only